# Need a regex to find a number and text in a filename

Tags: regex

Have filenames in the format:
021-05-05_10-10-12-111_Nancy_Test_123456-1234_194456454390816_OD_2021042911270.pdf
I need to find “123456-1234” and OD.

In the *123456-1234* number, the ‘-’ are wildcards so the number can be eg. *1234561234*, *123456**1234*, *123456_1234* - but there will always be 10 digits. (0-9) and the wildcard (if any) will be between the 6'th and 7'th digit.
The “OD” can be “OD” or “OS”, ignore case.

The number and OD/OS must be moved to the beginning of the filename with a server name in between, and today's date after OD/OS to uppercase.

Eg: 123456-1234_servername1_OD_yyyy_mm_dd_ss_021-05-05_10-10-12-111_Nancy_Test_194456454390816_2021042911270.pdf.

I'm using a file renaming program that will take the regex.  
(Don't know if advertising is allowed at StackOverflow, if it is, I will of course provide a link to the program).

This is what I got so far:  
`(?:_od_|_sd_)` gives me the OD or SD

`(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)` gives me the 1234561234 but only if there are no wildcards between the 6'th and 7'th digit.

Furthermore, I can't figure out how to put them together and move them in front with the server name in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)^(.*?)_(\d{6}\D*\d{4})_(\d+)_(od|sd)_
```

Replace with `$2_servername1_$4_yyyy_mm_dd_ss_$1_$3_`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8WwhpF/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d{6}\D*\d{4})` - Group 2: six digits, zero or more non-digits, four digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(od|sd)` - Group 4: `od` or `sd`
- `_` - an underscore

Comment: Can see there is a big mistake in my question, so sorry.
The first part works like charm, but I also need today's date in the output.
eg.  123456-1234_servername1_OD_**2022_01_03_12_45_27**_12021-05-05_10-10-12-111_Nancy_Test_194456454390816_OD_2021042911270.pdf.  (format: yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss)

Comment: @JonasHansen Great, when you create your replacement, just use some DateTime structure. Regex is just a pattern to match strings and replacement patterns can only contain backreferences to capturing groups in the regex pattern, you can't say "replace with today's date" to any regex.

Comment: OK, I didn't the part with "you can't say "replace with today's date" to any regex"